# Question regarding the definition of a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find all the elements that belong to set A. This set is given by:
$$A=\{X: X \subseteq \{3,2,a\} \ \land \ |X|=2\}$$

According to the set theory, $\ A \subseteq B\ $ if every element of $A$ is also an element of B.

I have found the following result:
$$A=\{\{3,3\},\{3,2\},\{3,a\},\{2,3\},\{2,2\},\{2,a\},\{a,3\},\{a,2\},\{a,a\}\}$$

Later on, I recall that set equality does not care about the order in which we list the elements. Therefore I can remove the elements such as {a,2},{a,3} and {2,3}:
$$A=\{\{3,3\},\{3,2\},\{3,a\},\{2,2\},\{2,a\},\{a,a\}\}$$

When I compared results with a friend he showed me this:
$$A=\{\{3,2\},\{3,a\},\{2,a\}\}$$

I'm not sure why there is a difference between both answers. If I had to justify this last answer I would take a guess by saying that given $x \in \{3,2,a\}$, set theory sees {x,x} as {x} and therefore the cardinality condition is not met in such cases.

Therefore, my two questions are:

1) Which one is the correct solution?

2) Is my guess correct?

Comment: Your friend is right and your guess about why is right. Sets do not have "repeated elements". A set with three elements has three two-element subsets.

Comment: Congratulation! You've discovered "multiset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $S=\{....\}$ means that the members of $S$ are all, and only, the things named or described by the "$....$"

For example $S=\{2,3\}$ means that any $x$ belongs to  $S$ iff $(x=2$ or $x=3).$

Since $(x=2$ or $x=3)\iff  (x=3$ or $x=2),$ therefore $\{2,3\}$ and $\{3,2\}$ have the same members so they are the same set.

And $T=\{2,2\}$ means any $y\in T$ iff $(y=2$ or $y=2),$ so $\{2,2\}=\{2\}.$